# Javascript object values display as NaN when defined

Tags: javascript

I have come across an unusual JS issue.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RD5a4/

Note that the fiddle wont produce any results, just console logs.

PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AcH79zZv

I am trying to create a timer and I have an object that is defined like this (code trimmed for legibility):

```
initiate_timer : function(options) {
timer = {
    id: options.id || "ticker",
    to_display: options.to_display || ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'],
    target_date: options.target_date || null,
    time_left: {
        in_days : "0",
        in_hours : "0",
        in_minutes : "0",
        in_seconds : "0"
      }
    }
}
```

Further down I calculate the time left and split it into days/hours/minutes/seconds so I can display it. When I display the object, timer, to the console the time_left displays correctly.

```
console.log( timer );
Object {
  time_left: Object {
    in_days: "00"
    in_hours: "00"
    in_minutes: 45
    in_seconds: 54
  }
}
```

But if I try to access time_left directly I suddenly only get NaN.

```
console.log( timer.time_left );
Object {
  in_days: NaN,
  in_hours: NaN, 
  in_minutes: NaN,
  in_seconds: NaN
}
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if I can clarify anything as it is certainly a confusing issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect an asynchronicity bug, or a problem with delayed log rendering, but we don't have enough code. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, I have added links to a JSFiddle which produces the issue. Also the pastebin of the JS (is there a better way of doing this). The two console.log lines are right next to each other which is the confusing part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that at the time of logging, your object is still not fully initialized and is full of `NaN`.

But the rendering in the console, for performance reasons, isn't immediate (apart usually for the first level of properties) : it's done later, when you open the object in the console (remember that a logged object is potentially very big or even cyclic so a browser could hardly always precompute the whole three).

A way to really see the object at logging time (assuming it's not too big or cyclic) is to use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(timer));
```

Comment: Note: if you have to log very big or cyclic objects (which you can't `stringify`), then you might use a library I made : [JSON.prune](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune).

Comment: Thanks for the response. While this might be accurate it doesn't actually solve the issue (which I perhaps didn't describe correctly). I also am unable to access the object using timer.time_left.days remaining. It isn't just a logging issue. I was able to rewrite the code to resolve the issue but I still don't know why this way didn't work.